# Why can sunlight heat an object on the other side of glass?

Tags: radiation

Q1. Why can sunlight heat an object on the other side of glass, but normal light from a CFL or Incandescent Light bulb can't.

Q2. Do they make a light bulb that can do this? I need to increase the tempature and objects inside a glass tank.

I'm fully aware of bulbs like the Floureon Ceramic Infrared Bulb Heat Emitter Reptile Lamp.

Comment: Who says the CFL or the incandescent bulb can't transmit heat to the object on the other side of the glass?  Just don't forget that the sunlight is a couple of orders of magnitude brighter than any lamp that you'd normally operate inside your home.

Comment: That ceramic heater "bulb" will work better _inside_ the tank.  It only emits long-wave IR, and the glass will absorb pretty much all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different types of "glass" transmit and block different types of radiation. When astronomers are making infrared instruments and they need to place a window in the instrument, they use [sapphire](http://www.valleydesign.com/sapppic.htm). Ordinary glass, similar to borosilicate in the plots on [this page](https://rayotek.com/techincal_info_glass_sapphire.htm), blocks infrared radiation that we normally think of as heat.

The way the sun heats up objects behind glass is by pouring enough visible and UV light through the glass to do the heating. The glass then blocks the infrared radiation from escaping, causing the heat to build up.